# Lying to prevent offense

Tags: kohen-priest, sheker-false, embarrassment

Is one permitted to lie to a woman by saying that he's a kohen and therefore unable to marry her, thus preventing him from offending/embarrassing her about the reason he refused her?  Are there sources on this or similar cases?

Comment: This really shouldn't be happening in the traditional Jewish system of shadchanim, you shouldn't be at the point of having to lie about why you think this isn't going to work (in that system, breaking off a shidduch in the early stages does not endanger shalom, so it's being unnecessarily deceptive- is there any other case where one is allowed to lie about being a Cohen,?). I don't think you'll find traditional sources that will answer this question. I'd avoid. CYLOR

Comment: You picked such a loaded example. Very geshmak.